# Template deduction and overloading

Tags: c++, templates

This is a Exercise in Primer c++ 5th:

```
template <typename T> void f(T);                   //1
template <typename T> void f(const T*);            //2
template <typename T> void g(T);                   //3
template <typename T> void g(T*);                  //4
int i = 42, *p = &i;
const int ci = 0, *p2 = &ci;
g(42); g(p); g(ci); g(p2);
f(42); f(p); f(ci); f(p2);
```

And here is the answer:

```
g(42);  //type: int(rvalue) call template 3  T: int          instantiation: void g(int)
g(p);   //type: int *       call template 4  T: int          instantiation: void g(int *)
g(ci);  //type: const int   call template 3  T: const int    instantiation: void g(const int)
g(p2);  //type: const int * call template 4  T: const int    instantiation: void g(const int *)
f(42);  //type: int(rvalue) call template 1  T: int          instantiation: void f(int)
f(p);   //type: int *       call template 1  T: int *        instantiation: void f(int *)
f(ci);  //type: const int   call template 1  T: const int    instantiation: void f(const int)
f(p2);  //type: const int * call template 2  T：int          instantiation: void f(const int *)
```

My question is why `f(p)` favors instantiation of `f(T)` instead of `f(const T *)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In brief, the rules for including function templates in overload resolution are:

1. Name lookup determines a set of functions, objects, and function templates that are visible.
2. Each function template in the set determines its template arguments from any explicit arguments, deduction, and/or default template arguments, and those are substituted to get one specific concrete function signature if possible.  (When not possible, the function template is just tossed out of the set.  This can happen when template argument deduction fails, and when substituting arguments into the signature fails, aka the "SFINAE" rule.)
3. The functions are compared using the normal overload resolution rules, treating the signatures that came from templates exactly as though they were ordinary non-template functions.
4. Only if step 3 would consider two of the functions ambiguous, these tie-breakers apply:

   a. If one function signature came from a template and one did not, the non-template function is considered better.

   b. If both function signatures came from templates and one template is "more specialized" than the other, the more specialized template is considered better.  (Briefly, "more specialized" means essentially that we can prove any valid arguments to the  more specialized template are also valid arguments to the less specialized template, but not vice-versa.)

In this example's `f(p)` expression, in step 2 template #1 deduces `T=int*` and template #2 deduces `T=int`, so the signatures are:

```
void f(int*);        // from 1
void f(const int*);  // from 2
```

In step 3, the argument `p` has type `int*`, so `void f(int*);` from #1 uses the Identity conversion (an Exact Match), and `void f(const int*);` from #2 uses a Pointer Conversion, so `void f(int*);` from #1 wins, and that function template specialization is the one named.

It's true that template #2 `void f(const T*);` is more specialized than template #1 `void f(T);`.  But since step 3 determined the answer, we never get to step 4, so that doesn't matter here.  (Step 4 does come in for the other expression `f(p2)`.)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) answer, but basically:

`f(T)` with `T=int*` is an exact match for `int*`

`f(T const*)` with `T=int` is not an exact match for `int*`.

Exact matches win.

Comment: what do you mean exact match . If match happens after template deduction, and ```int *``` is a better matched case than ```const int *```?